# Print sum of unique values of an integer array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I am yet again stuck at the answer. This program prints the unique values but I am unable to get the sum of those unique values right. Any help is appreciated

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int sum = 0;
    Integer[] numbers = {1,2,23,43,23,56,7,9,11,12,12,67,54,23,56,54,43,2,1,19};
    Set<Integer> setUniqueNumbers = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();

    for (int x : numbers) {
        setUniqueNumbers.add(x);
    }
    for (Integer x : setUniqueNumbers) {
       System.out.println(x);   
       for (int i=0; i<=x; i++){
           sum += i;
       }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: You are summing i, the index, instead of the value from the set.

Comment: What is the `for (int i=0; i<=x; i++)` loop supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great example for making use of the Java 8 language additions:

```
int sum = Arrays.stream(numbers).distinct().collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));
```

This line would replace everything in your code starting at the `Set` declaration until the last line before the `System.out.println`.

Comment: Or a bit shorter: `Arrays.stream(numbers).distinct().mapToInt(i -> i).sum()`

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for this loop

```
for (int i=0; i<=x; i++){
    sum += i;
}
```

Because you're adding `i` rather than the actual integers in the set. What's happening here is that you're adding all the numbers from 0 to x to `sum`. So for `23`, you're not increasing `sum` by 23, instead, you're adding 1+2+3+4+5+....+23 to `sum`. All you need to do is add x, so the above loop can be omitted and replaced with a simple line of adding x to `sum`,

```
sum += x;
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error always occures if one pokes around in low level loops etc.
Best is, to get rid of low level code and use Java 8 APIs:

```
Integer[] numbers = {1,2,23,43,23,56,7,9,11,12,12,67,54,23,56,54,43,2,1,19};

int sum = Arrays.stream(numbers)
         .distinct()
         .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
         .sum();
```

In this way there is barely any space for mistakes.
If you have an int array, the code is even shorter:

```
int[] intnumbers = {1,2,23,43,23,56,7,9,11,12,12,67,54,23,56,54,43,2,1,19};
int sumofints = Arrays.stream(intnumbers)
               .distinct()
               .sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is my first time commenting anywhere and I just really wanted to share my way of printing out only the unique values in an array without the need of any utilities.

```
//The following program seeks to process an array to remove all duplicate integers.
//The method prints the array before and after removing any duplicates

public class NoDups
{
    //we use a void static void method as I wanted to print out the array without any duplicates. Doing it like this negates the need for any additional code after calling the method
    static void printNoDups(int array[]) 
    {   //Below prints out the array before any processing takes place
        System.out.println("The array before any processing took place is: ");
        System.out.print("{");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[i]);
            if (i != array.length - 1)
                System.out.print(", ");
        }
        System.out.print("}");
        System.out.println("");
        //the if and if else statements below checks if the array contains more than 1 value as there can be no duplicates if this is the case
        if (array.length==0)
            System.out.println("That array has a length of 0.");
        else if (array.length==1)
            System.out.println("That array only has one value: " + array[0]);
        else //This is where the fun begins
        {   
            System.out.println("Processed Array is: ");
            System.out.print( "{" + array[0]);//we print out the first value as it will always be printed (no duplicates has occured before it)

            for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) //This parent for loop increments once the all the checks below are run
            {
                int check = 0;//this variable tracks the amount of times an value has appeared
                for(int h = 0; h < i; h++) //This loop checks the current value for array[i] against all values before it
                {
                    if (array[i] == array[h])
                        {
                        ++check; //if any values match during this loop, the check value increments
                        }
                }
                if (check != 1) //only duplicates can result in a check value other than 1
                {
                    System.out.print(", " + array[i]);
                }
            }       
        }
            System.out.print("}"); //formatting
            System.out.println("");

    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    { //I really wanted to be able to request an input from the user but so that they could just copy and paste the whole array in as an input.
        //I'm sure this can be done by splitting the input on "," or " " and then using a for loop to add them to the array but I dont want to spend too much time on this as there are still many tasks to get through!
        //Will come back and revisit to add this if I remember.
        int inpArray[] = {20,100,10,80,70,1,0,-1,2,10,15,300,7,6,2,18,19,21,9,0}; //This is just a test array

        printNoDups(inpArray);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the bug is on the line

```
sum += i;
```

it should be

```
sum += x;
```